# Visual Studio Building static lib gets unresolved external symbol

Tags: c, visual-studio, libssh

I am statically building LibSSH on Windows and managed to build it with cmake-gui. If I build the resulting Visual Studio project, I get the ssh.lib file. However, if I link this .lib file to another project where I need it, I receive following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _BN_bn2hex referenced in function _ssh_print_bignum  Project1    C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project1\Project1\ssh.lib(bignum.obj) 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _DH_new referenced in function _ssh_dh_set_parameters    Project1    C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project1\Project1\ssh.lib(dh_crypto.obj)  1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _DH_free referenced in function _ssh_dh_cleanup  Project1    C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project1\Project1\ssh.lib(dh_crypto.obj)  1
```

And like ~250 more of these.

I found these object files on my system in another directory of the LibSSH project, but don't know what to do with these.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: From the names (for example `new` and `free`, the prefixes might be C++ clobber) shown: Are you linking the C++ standard libraries?

Comment: I am programming in C and linking the stanard libraries, yes.

Comment: Then you need to look for `new` in function `_ssh_dh_set_parameters` of file `dh_crypto.c`, for example. Is it a variable or a function? Where is it defined? And so on... The error messages give enough hints to start debugging your build.